# BrowserWindow in electron does not open

Tags: electron

I just tried to test electron environment for programming with JavaScript on desktop with Windows 10.

So I have an app:

```
const electron=require("electron");
const app=electron.app;
const BrowserWindow=electron.BrowserWindow;

var mainWindow=null;

app.on("ready",function(){
  mainWindow=new BrowserWindow({height:600,width:800});
  mainWindow.loadURL("file://"+__dirname+"index.html");
});
```

and index.html is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> MyIndex.html </title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World from Electron!<br>
</body>
</html>
```

and package.json is:

```
{
"name":"Electron-Test",
"version":"0.1.0",
"main":"./main.js",
"scripts":{"start":"electron ."}
}
```

If I run `electron .` or `npm start` the application seems to start, but no browser window opens. On console I have to press `Ctrl-C` to stop the application.
Does anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

try to add one more`/`after file:

 you are also missing a `/`  before `index.html`

```
app.on("ready",function(){
  mainWindow=new BrowserWindow({height:600,width:800});
  mainWindow.loadURL("file:///"+__dirname+"/index.html");
});
```

i saw it in this video, at 3:32 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0AkgNv4U4E

Comment: Ok, I started the script at another computer (win7). Your right, there is a slash missing. My problem with the windows 10 installation is, that now window opens at all, i.e. also not an empty window. On my windows 7 machine all works well.